# Merge non empty values from a table to one result row

Tags: mysql, select, merge, group-by

I have a MYSQL table which has about 350 columns. There are most 'empty' values and I need to merge several rows in one and replace 'empty' values by a non empty value. My table looks like this:

```
id|col1|col2|col3|cola|col_b|...|col350
1 |12  |4   |3   |-77 |-77  |...|-77 
2 |12  |-77 |-77 |2   |-77  |...|-77 
3 |12  |-77 |-77 |-77 |6    |...|-77 
4 |12  |-77 |-77 |-77 |-77  |...|6
5 |13  |3   |-77 |-77 |-77  |...|-77 
6 |13  |-77 |5   |-77 |-77  |...|-77
...
```

`-77` is a replacement for empty values. In `col1` is an id of datasets witch belongs together.

I need a select query to merge non 'empty' values to one result row per col1-id. For col1-id 12 it should looks like this:

```
1 | 12 | 4 | 3 | 2 | 6 | ... | 6
```

Does someone have an idea how to do this?

Comment: 350 columns in a table, and they're all alike like this? You really need to normalize the schema.

Comment: It is a csv import from 3rd party software.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT col1, 
       MAX(CASE WHEN col2 <> -77 THEN col2 END) AS col2,
       MAX(CASE WHEN col3 <> -77 THEN col3 END) AS col3,
       MAX(CASE WHEN cola <> -77 THEN cola END) AS cola,
       MAX(CASE WHEN col_b <> -77 THEN col_b END) AS col_b,
       ... and so on
       MAX(CASE WHEN col350 <> -77 THEN col350 END) AS col350
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY col1
```

Comment: Would not work, becouse column names are not numeric. For example: there is no col4, cola instead.

Comment: Just use whatever the actual column names are. I thought those were just examples.